# Move base make plan sending incomplete paths over rosbridge

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the move_base/make_path to send a path over to a websocket (Rosbridge) to a different device.  Unfortunately,  I am getting an inomplete Yaml packet.  My max packet size is set to infinite for both the linux and the windows machine.  Can I make the points in between the path larger?   And why is my path not sending all the way.   (Timing issue maybe)

Any help would be great!

Here is an example of what I am getting back.  Notice the end just cuts off.

Got a message {"values": {"plan": {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 0, "nsecs": 0}, "frame_id": "", "seq": 0}, "poses": [{"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.07999999821186066, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.01652093373564778, "x": 0.06481661651693393, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.02430633252174408, "x": 0.05854066717906292, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.031909136058930976, "x": 0.052044714718057605, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.04099274543689013, "x": 0.047862843397345145, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.05019877798410999, "x": 0.043957852334726155, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.060104769316954076, "x": 0.042589892389106154, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.07004680476978109, "x": 0.0415147438306791, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.08001498997177947, "x": 0.04071773438041504, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.09000228680665145, "x": 0.04021376043080327, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.09999999776482582, "x": 0.03999999910593033, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.11999999731779099, "x": 0.019999999552965164, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.13999999687075615, "x": 0.019999999552965164, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.1599999964237213, "x": 0.019999999552965164, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.17999999597668648, "x": 0.019999999552965164, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.19999999552965164, "x": 0.019999999552965164, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0.0, "z": 0.0, "w": 1.0}}}, {"header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1498427833, "nsecs": 23645176}, "frame_id": "map", "seq": 0}, "pose": {"position": {"y": 0.2199999950826168, "x": 0.019999999552965164, "z": 0.0}, "orientation": {"y": 0.0, "x": 0

Any help would be great!

Thanks
BT

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264717/move-base-make-plan-sending-incomplete-paths-over-rosbridge/) by [BlackManta](https://answers.ros.org/users/428/blackmanta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never mind, I have a bizarre issue with my read.

---

Originally posted by [BlackManta](https://answers.ros.org/users/428/blackmanta/) with karma: 56 on 2017-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-26**:
Could you perhaps tell us -- and future readers of your question -- a little more about the 'bizarre issue' with your 'read'? That might save some frustration if they come across the same problem.